# Is there an inverse behavior to the "else" in a for-else loop?

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop which tests for a condition. I would like to execute some code if the condition was never met. The following code does the opposite:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for k in a:
    if k == 2:
        break
else:
    print("no match")
```

"no match" is printed if the `break` is not reached (for a condition like `k == 10` for instance). Is there a construction which would do the opposite, i.e. run some code if the `break` is reached?

I know I can do something like

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
match = False
for k in a:
    if k == 2:
        match = True
if match:
    print("match")
```

but was looking for a more compact solution, without the flag variable..

**Note**: I now realize from the answers that I did not make it clear that I would like to move the "matched" code outside of the for loop. It will be rather large and I would like to avoid hiding it in the for loop (thus the idea of the flag variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your condition inside of a function or a comprehension, you can use the `any` keyword to accomplish this in a very *pythonic* way.

```
if not any(k == 2 for k in a):
    print 'no match'
```

If you were to move the condition to a function that returns a boolean, you could generalize this:

```
def f(x):
    return x == 2

if not any(f(k) for k in a):
    print 'no match'
```

Comment: Thanks - this does (albeit in a completely different way) exactly what I wanted: a compact way to check for the condition before firing up the code if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just put it before the `break`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for k in a:
    if k == 2:
        print("found")    # HERE
        break
else:
    print("no match")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I realize that I did not make it clear that I wanted to have the code outside the loop (it will be large). I updated the question.

Comment: If you want to do that, use the flag. This is not such a common use case that there is a language feature for it.

Comment: @WoJ Look at Mike's answer, specifically the second snippet: the body of your loop would reside in `f`, and the bottom condition is completely separated.

Comment: @Kroltan: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for (accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for k in a:
    if k == 2:
        print("match")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I realize that I did not make it clear that I wanted to have the code outside the loop (it will be large). I updated the question.